# Is it possible to limit publish_actions permissions to a single album?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.1

My facebook app needs publish_actions permissions to post photos to user albums.  It works great.  However, I would like my app to be more restricted and only be able to publish to certain albums.  I know I can show the users a list of available albums and use my code to restrict the access.  But it seems there should be a way to limit publish_actions per album.  Is it possible to request publish_actions for only a given album?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don´t you just show that one Album to the user? Make sure you don´t restrict "by id" (because it´s different for every user, of course) but by ablum name, of course. There´s no other way to restrict this, but you can easily restrict it on your own.

Comment: I think you are suggesting what I said in my 4th sentence.  That will certainly work.  I am new to facebook development and still learning.  I guess facebook expects the developer to be responsible and not post to the wrong albums.  You said "by id... different for every user".  I may be misunderstanding you.    You mean the UserID changes per user?? Not the AlbumID.  Right?

Comment: no, i mean the album id. every album got a unique id on facebook.

Comment: and you can only request publish_actions, there is no selective approval.